# How lifecycle methods in react Js are working with the variable unsubfromAuth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```
class App extends Component{
constructor(){
super() 
this.state = {
  currentuser : null
}}
  
unsubfromAuth = null

componentDidMount(){

this.unsubfromAuth =  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  this.setState({currentuser : user})
  console.log(user)
})
  }
 componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubfromAuth()
  }
render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Header currentUser={this.state.currentuser}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/Hats" component={Hats}/>
          <Route exact path="/shoes" component={Shoes}/>
          <Route exact path="/jackets" component={Jacket}/>
          <Route exact path="/men" component={Men}/>
          <Route exact path="/women" component={Women}/>
          <Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop}/>
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>      
    </div>
  )
}}

export default App
```

Why it is used in ComponentWillUnmount? I heard something about memory leak, does it prevents from it?
why it was changed in ComponentDidMount? I'm using firebase in Reactjs.

Comment: If this is one file please format it in a single code block. This is hard to read. Also you're missing closing brackets and the indentation is messed up.

Comment: Yes, it's from one file and I took the chunk that I was confused in, I had multiple questions that's why I separated it with multiple blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard flow in a React Component lifecycle, when you have to subscribe to some event.
This is just the initialization of the instance variable, it is executed as soon as the Component is mounted:

```
unsubfromAuth = null
```

This is where you effectively subscribe to your event ("auth-state-changed") and start to listen to it, you want always to subscribe to events like this in `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` if you use hooks, since this is executed when the Component has fully mounted.

The method `auth.onAuthStateChanged()` returns a function that automatically clears any subscription when called.

```
componentDidMount(){

this.unsubfromAuth =  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  this.setState({currentuser : user})
  console.log(user)
})
  }
```

The unsubscription method will be called in:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubfromAuth()
  }
```

This will be executed just before the Component is going to unmount to clear the subscription, since you don't want your event listeners, and subscriptions to keep being in memory when you unmount, or you will end up with memory leaks if your component mounts and unmounts many times.

Comment: Is "componentWillUnmount()" working automatically every time, componentDidMount() is executed whenever I press "Sign in" button?

Comment: No, componentWillUnmount, as the name suggests, executes only when the Component is unmounting. In React a Component unmounts when it gets taken out of Virtual DOM tree, for example:
{`boolean ? <Component /> : null}`  This expression in your JSX will mount and unmount <Component /> when boolean is toggled between `true` and `false` state.

Comment: Okayyy, so when its null it'll automatically unmount the component?

Comment: Yes if it renders `null`, the <Component /> automatically gets unmounted if it was previously mounted.